# Hiding black bars in letterboxed thumbnail

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a user control that shows a thumbnail and some text below it. The API I'm using returns a 480x360 letterboxed thumbnail. I'm trying to hide it so the user only sees the image without the two 45px tall bars on the top an bottom. Below are the dimensions of the thumbnail:
[image]

User Control xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="ThumbnailRow"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="..." Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="Gray">
            <TextBlock Padding="24" Text="..." HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In my codebehind, I tried to modify the height of `ThumbnailViewRow` to hide the black bars:

```
private double GetScreenWidth()
{
    double scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel;  
    double width = scaleFactor * Window.Current.Bounds.Width;

    return width;
}

private double GetAdjustedThumbnailRowHeight()
{
    // 38 represents 19px left & right margins in ListView
    double adjustedWidth = GetScreenWidth() - 38; 
    double projectedHeight = (360 * adjustedWidth) / 480;

    // in a full 480x360 image, I would need to shave 45 px from the top
    // and bottom. In some resolutions, the image is scaled so I have
    // to find the proportionate amount to trim
    double toTrim = (projectedHeight * 90) / 360;

    return projectedHeight - toTrim;
}

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ThumbnailViewRow.Height = new GridLength(GetAdjustedThumbnailRowHeight());
}
```

The above code only slightly works; a large portion of the bars are still visible on both ends. On a 480x800 device, I was able to tweak some numbers to get the thumbnail to display correctly. The fix in that case was to multiply `toTrim` by 1.55 but I have no clue how well this would work out on devices with other resolutions. I don't have another device to test nor a WP emulator.

Could the reason for this problem be an embarrassing math mistake, or a subtlety in the way XAML works? How can I get my approach to work properly in different resolutions?

Here's a quick working example I made in WPF. (Note the explicitly-set height and width).
[image]

```
<Grid Margin="0, 30, 0, 0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- 360 - 45 - 45 = 270 -->
        <RowDefinition Height="270"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="..." VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="480" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Clip Property of the Image like so

```
<Image x:Name="myimage" Stretch="None" Source="/Assets/my_image.jpg">
    <Image.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 45, 480, 435"></RectangleGeometry>
    </Image.Clip>
</Image>
```

RECT is the rectangle section of the image you want to be visible.

Comment: Awesome! The solution was to clip the unstretched image and put in in a `ViewBox`. Thank you very much!